# xcode Instruments - can't find leak

Tags: xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

I'm having a problem that is really doing my head in.

So basically I have a MainMenuScene, which in turns creates a test layer. This layer is very simple as it only creates a score label and a button that is added to a menu.
When this button is pressed the MainMenuScene is replaced by a blank scene and then the MainMenuScene is loaded again.

So far so good. However the problem is when I take a heapshot in the instruments each time the scene is reloaded, I get a heap increase of around 20kb. When I dig deeper in the extended view it seems the sprite and font from the testLayer aren't being released and yet the dealloc method from the layer is being called.

I also add ARC support to my files except core Cocos files. Could this be related in any way?

Here is the test layer:

```
@implementation TestLayer

-(id)init
{
    self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(2,2,2,210)];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // ask director the the window size
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

        NSNumber * n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[SDCloudUserDefaults integerForKey:@"highscore"]];

        NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:n];

        //score
        CCLabelBMFont * scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:string fntFile:@"scoreFont.fnt" width:s.width alignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter];
        scoreLabel.position =  ccp( POS_X(443), POS_Y(877) );
        [self addChild:scoreLabel z:90];

        //PLAY BUTTON
       CCMenuItemSprite *playButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"play_up.png"]
                                                               selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"play_down.png"]
                                                                       target:self
                                                                     selector:@selector(Transition:)];

        playButton.position = ccp( POS_X(380) , POS_Y(177));

        menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: playButton, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(0, 0);
        [self addChild: menu];

       }
    return self;
}

-(void) Transition:(ccTime) dt
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(Transition:)];
    [[SceneManager sharedSceneManager]RunSceneWithID:SCENE_LOADING:eCCTransitionCrossFade:1.0f];

}

- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
}
@end
```

I really can't see what is wrong with this.

Thanks

Comment: What is prompting your optimization? Are you getting a memory crash? A heap shot difference of 20K doesn't sound like a whole lot to me. Is this just pre-mature optimization? I can understand that it bothers you that memory is growing. It would bother me too, but is it a problem?

Comment: @Matt Long the size is only 20kb because is a small test layer. If I use the original layer the leak is about 400kb :(

Answer (score 0):

Right, I did the same test on an unARCed project with all the correct calls to [super dealloc] etc, and got the exact same behavior.

However, after closer inspection, I'm still not sure if I have leaks or I'm not interpreting the results correctly.

So I have the program on an initial state and take a heapshot. I then press the ui button that makes the scene to be replaced and then reloaded. I get back to the initial state and take another heapshot and notice that the heap had a growth of around 20kb or so. When i press the ui button again the previous heapshot goes back to zero bytes. After doing this a few time, the previous heapshot goes always back to zero bytes.

Because in cocos2d everytime you replace a scene everything attached to that scene is deallocated, and when you come back to it, everything is allocated again. So I think there will always be an heap growth because that growth is the size of the Scene with that layer as a child. Does this make sense?

Also i noticed that everytime I did this, the #Living column in the statistics was not increasing, which is a good sign, right?